# summing rows based on one hot variables

Tags: python, pandas

I think the code below is OK but seems to clumsy. Basically, I want to go from here:

[image]

to here:

[image]

Basically adding column Result if the dummy column is 1. Hope this makes sense?

```
data = {'Dummy1':[0, 0, 1, 1],
        'Dummy2':[1, 1, 0, 0],
        'Result':[1, 1, 2, 2]}

haves = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(haves)

melted = pd.melt(haves, id_vars=['Result'])
melted = melted.loc[melted["value"] > 0]

print(melted)

wants = melted.groupby(["variable"])["Result"].sum()

print(wants)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to `melt`, perform a simple multiplication and `sum`:

```
wants = haves.drop('Result', axis=1).mul(haves['Result'], axis=0).sum()
```

output:

```
Dummy1    4
Dummy2    2
dtype: int64
```

Intermediate:

```
>>> haves.drop('Result', axis=1).mul(haves['Result'], axis=0)

    Dummy1  Dummy2
0       0       1
1       0       1
2       2       0
3       2       0
```

###### Shorter variant

**Warning: this mutates the original dataframe, which will lose the 'Result' column.**

```
wants = haves.mul(haves.pop('Result'), axis=0).sum()
```